# By using the properties of determinant show that

Tags: matrices, determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\
1&b&b^2\\
1&c&c^2\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}1&a&0\\
0&1&b\\
0&1&c\end{vmatrix}$$

I have been trying to solve this equation for about 2 weeks now but without any luck can any one help me with a simple solution for this? (if available ofcourse) or even a complex one doesn't really matter I just want to have a solution for it..

Comment: I recommend you to google Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: I don't really know much about matrices, I'm a CS student I just have a linear exam tomorrow and one of the marked as "very important" questions was this so a solution will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You may refer the example in [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint**: How is $$\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\1&b&b^2\\1&c&c^2\end{vmatrix}$$ related to $$\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\0&b-a&b^2-a^2\\0&c-a&c^2-a^2\end{vmatrix}?$$

How is $$\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\0&1&a+b\\0&1&a+c\end{vmatrix}$$ related to $$\begin{vmatrix}1&a&0\\0&1&b\\0&1&c\end{vmatrix}?$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28807/discussion-on-answer-by-cameron-buie-by-using-the-properties-of-determinant-show).

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\1&b&b^2\\1&c&c^2\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\0&(b-a)&(b^2-a^2)\\0&(c-a)&(c^2-a^2)\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\0&1&(b+a)\\0&1&(c+a)\end{vmatrix} \dots (1)=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\0&1&(b+a)\\0&0&(c-b)\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2\\0&1&(b+a)\\0&0&1\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\begin{vmatrix}1&a&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{vmatrix}=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a).$$

After $(1)$ do the following,
$$\implies (b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}1&a&0\\0&1&b\\0&1&c\end{vmatrix} \text{ doing column operation.}$$

Comment: I did not get your point. Is there any mistake? Please tell me the step number.

Comment: Oho. Yes, I got your point. Thanks. Ya, that is a silly mistake. Sorry.

Comment: umm the prove asks for another result isn't yours is different from the result required?

Comment: can you please explain ( doing column operation ) ?

Comment: $C3 \leftarrow C3 -aC2$

Comment: Don't really get this :/ can you do further explaining ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to say further.

Comment: @Lawa, Rajada is just using the properties of the determinant of matrix, like that it is invariant with respect to column and row manipulations

Comment: Oh I got it now thanks for explaining :)